# How do I manually send a password reset request in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

I would like to manually send a password reset request to a specific user (not the one currently logged in) from within a controller. I did some digging around in the Laravel code and it seems like I should be calling `postEmail(Request $request)` in `ResetsPasswords`, but I can't seem to figure out how to get access to the right `PasswordController` instance to call it.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, it's hard to help without you showing us some code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are admin, so from your end, you can set a column in database (is_active), and change that to 0, and check when user logged in if `is_active == 0`. If it's 0, allow him to set a new password, then make a hash of new password and change `is_active` to 1